# Notepad++ : How to remove everything in a multiple lines except words in Capital

Tags: notepad++

I get a text of stock tickers which has ticker in Capital letter along with earnings expected numbers. Its a pretty big list and going thru all of them manually is a long process. Is there any way I can extract just the tickers which are in capitals in Notepad++ .Here is the same of what I get

```
EGHT
-0.17-0.06
Adtalem Global EducationATGE
0.550.74
AflacAFL
1.011.02
AllstateALL
3.221.24
AmdocsDOX
```

I am looking to convert this to --

```
EGHT 
ATGE 
AFL 
ALL 
DOX
```

Comment: You should you regex find and replace with empty string

Comment: Zulander, Could you please elaborate. I am new to Notepad++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use these parameters in the "Replace" window:

Find what: `([^A-Z]|^)((?![A-Z]{2}).)*`
Replace with: `\n`
☑ Match case
◉ Regular expression
☑ `.` matches newline
<kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Comment: Thank you trincot. This worked perfectly. Now this saves me ton of time :)